Collapse from Bootstrap site does not work
I am trying to learn collapsing with bootstrap and I copied the code directly from the site and it does not work when I paste it into my own html file. Can someone help me figure this out?
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-    EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button"    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Link with href
      </a>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-    target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Button with data-bs-target
      </button>
    </p>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
      </div>
    </div>

Here is the JS FIDDLE
JS FIDDLE
I just copied some code. It works on their site but it does not work when I copy and paste the code. Am I missing something?

You need the bootstrap.bundle.min.js script too
cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

You suggestion seems to work on the Fiddle but for some odd reason it is not working on my file.

@JohnKim well then you need to show us what exactly you did "on your file", we can't guess that.

Probably you lack the cross origin property? Just copy this src to the end of your file:

Try these links?


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/684/600/400" class="card-img-top" alt="">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>



